# How can I black out the first few frames of a video with AVISynth?

Tags: video-processing, avisynth

I tried this:

```
black = BlankClip(length=10)
video = AVISource("@source1") 
overlay(video,black)
```

But now the whole video is black, not only the first 10 frames... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overlay does not automatically end, remember you can also overlay an image instead of a video for instance.

Give a frame for the end of the overlay and then continue the original video from there, like so:

```
overlay(video, black).trim(0, 10) + video.trim(11, framecount(video))
```